# Crontab skip run once a week

Tags: linux, cron, airflow-scheduler

I have a CRON expression that will run a given command every 8 hours, beginning at 00:00.

```
0 0,8,16 * * *
```

This will run a given commend 21 times a week, however, my goal is to skip one of these 21 runs *on a weekly basis*. What is the proper CRON expression to *skip* the first run on Sunday each week at 00:00 (in other words, an expression that will run 20 times per week)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it 2 lines:

`0 0,8,16 * * 0-5` At minute 0 past hour 0, 8, and 16 on every day-of-week from Sunday through Friday.

And

`0 8,16 * * 6` At minute 0 past hour 8 and 16 on Saturday.

You can change the day and hour which you want to skip, but there is no way to do this in 1 line as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Place this: `[[ ( $( date +\%u ) -ne 0 ) && ( $( date +\%H:\%M) != "00:00" ) ]] &&` before your command.

If you don't want to use `bash` for your cron-job, this works with `sh`:

```
[  $( date +\%u ) -ne 0  ] && [ $( date +\%H:\%M) != "00:00"  ] &&
```

Comment: By default, cron use `sh`, so may fail to understand `[[`.

Comment: Fair comment @Philippe ...